# "Project From Cylinder" suddenly working improperly in 2.79b

Tags: uv

I am not very knowledgeable about the program, I should start with.

Today I was messing around with some simple models and for some reason, either a keypress or a setting change, the "Project From Cylinder" UVmapping option stopped working right.

Normally it will project a nice even map when mapping something from a head-on view in orthographic perspective, and will even readily tile/wrap when moved to the proper area of my textures.

It has started projecting tubes that look more like results of "Project from View." They are incredibly stretched and have no boundaries on screen. It is essentially just the shape of the object I'm attempting to UV. It is also ignoring the seams I put on the model to attempt to compensate for this.

Is there some setting or toggle I activated? I was mapping somewhat spherical shapes just fine right up until I started getting these results.

I am only using two third-party addons. The Source SMD tools and NifTools for Blender.

[image: Proper unwrapping, or at least what I want.]

Proper unwrapping, or at least what I want.

[image: What I'm getting. Clearly not right.]

What I'm getting. Clearly not right.

It seems to work on spheres but not vague cylinders?? What gives?
It won't even project a single row of faces properly. Yet if I select other objects they unwrap just fine. What did I set on some of these, or do?

Comment: Any ideas? I made many models out of a few base models, and only some are affected by this peculiar problem. If I unwrap them with the plain unwrap command I can get good UVs after some tedious work. The unaffected models unwrap as they have the past few weeks I've been modeling, and it works even on non-cylindrical shapes without any defined seams...

Comment: could you please share your your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Would a dropbox link work? I could certainly provide one.

Comment: or http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51552             I notice that it affects similarly shaped models to those unaffected, as though the effect is caused by a setting rather than a normal error. I apologize for the lack of labeling of the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *Set Origin to Geometry* and it will unwrap (*Cylinder Projection*) correctly. I've never noticed that before though...

Comment: That seems to be it. Thank you for the help and time. It makes a lot of sense though as the origins have wandered quite a lot throughout this specific modeling session.